# Multi match boolean boost

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do the following

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/magento/customer/_search?pretty=1 -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "john",
                        "fields": [
                            "firstname"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase_prefix"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "bro",
                        "fields": [
                            "lastname"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase_prefix",
                        "boost": 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "sul",
                        "fields": [
                            "lastname"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase_prefix",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'
```

It's returning me results with Johnnie SultXXXX before Johnnie BrousXXXX (redacted).

Seems like the boost isn't being applied properly?  I've tried checking out the elasticsearch docs on booleans:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

They have the `boost` under the `bool` node which doesn't really make any sense, you usually want to boost a specific one of the boolean `should`s...?

UPDATE:

I haven't created any field mappings when creating the index.

Here are the results of an `explain`:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "_index": "magento",
    "_type": "customer",
    "_id": "6043",
    "matched": true,
    "explanation": {
    "value": 2.3943894,
        "description": "product of:",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": 3.591584,
                "description": "sum of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 1.795792,
                        "description": "sum of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 1.795792,
                                "description": "weight(firstname:johnnie in 8931) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.795792,
                                        "description": "score(doc=8931,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.18156901,
                                                "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                "details": [
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 9.89041,
                                                        "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=14524)"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 0.018358087,
                                                        "description": "queryNorm"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 9.89041,
                                                "description": "fieldWeight in 8931, product of:",
                                                "details": [
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 1,
                                                        "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                                        "details": [
                                                            {
                                                                "value": 1,
                                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 9.89041,
                                                        "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=14524)"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 1,
                                                        "description": "fieldNorm(doc=8931)"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 1.795792,
                        "description": "sum of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 1.795792,
                                "description": "weight(lastname:sultXXXX in 8931) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.795792,
                                        "description": "score(doc=8931,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.18156901,
                                                "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                "details": [
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 9.89041,
                                                        "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=14524)"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 0.018358087,
                                                        "description": "queryNorm"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 9.89041,
                                                "description": "fieldWeight in 8931, product of:",
                                                "details": [
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 1,
                                                        "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                                        "details": [
                                                            {
                                                                "value": 1,
                                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 9.89041,
                                                        "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=14524)"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "value": 1,
                                                        "description": "fieldNorm(doc=8931)"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "value": 0.6666667,
                "description": "coord(2/3)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I know that the `should`s are matching, because without them, I get a different first result than with them.

I hope that I'm using `phrase_prefix` properly in this context.  It's not entirely clear to me from the docs.  This page references them (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix) but only within the context of a regular `query`, not a `multi_match`.

Comment: Have a look at the explain output. I suspect that none of the should clauses actually match, but it depends on how your data is indexed. Maybe you can post your mapping for the lastname field? Also, have one more look at the reference for the phrase_prefix, I think you misunderstood what it does.

Comment: Thanks Luca!  I hadn't been aware of the explain feature, that's pretty sweet.  Posting the contents above.  I took another look at `phrase_prefix` docs here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix - not sure if that's the best place to look.  It seems like it should match the beginning of the phrase ("sul") against the `lastname` field?

Comment: match_phrase_prefix makes sense with multiple terms, for basic as you type suggestions. Only the last term will be used as a prefix. If you look at the example in the reference that should be clear. I don't understand what you're using phrase_prefix for here, sorry!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why only the last term in a search phrase would be used as a prefix, but I see that in the reference documentation, yes.  That doesn't make a lot of sense to me logically though.  I posted a separate question explaining the business logic I'm trying to implement on a higher level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366927/multiple-field-autocomplete-with-index-type-boost - it's a pretty straight forward use case really.

Comment: Expanding prefixes is expensive, that's it. An inverted index is made for exact matches rather than wildcard queries and such.