# Multiple field autocomplete with index type boost

Tags: elasticsearch

What I'm trying to accomplish on a high level is an autocomplete input field which queries both customers and orders on multiple fields, with customers ranking higher for customer name searches.

It seems to me that there are various ways to approach this problem with the tools that elasticsearch provides.

The way that I have approached this is to use `multi_match` queries with `prefix_phrase` type in order to get partial queries to work across multiple fields.

For example, "bo" should return back matches for "Bob Smith" as well as "Adam Boss".  I'm indexing fullname as a separate field from firstname and lastname, so that "adam boss" will return a valid prefix match as well.

In addition, I'd like to boost customer results - trying to do that with a [`boost` param on the multi_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322885/multi-match-boolean-boost), but that doesn't seem to be working the way I'd expect it to.

What would be a straight forward way to tackle this problem?

One of the challenges I'm facing with the elasticsearch docs is that it's not always clear which properties and features apply to which others.  For example, the [multi_match documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) doesn't talk about using a custom boost, other than on a field-level.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is using completion suggester of ES (v0.90.3+), please refer here for a real use case:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: Thanks Duc, I had checked that out at one point but ran into some issues with it.  I'll take a closer look.